# Inner join mysql performance search products

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables:

```
~ 100k records
CREATE TABLE `words` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `word` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_slovak_ci NOT NULL,
  `reverse` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_slovak_ci NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `word ` (`word`),
  UNIQUE KEY `reverse ` (`reverse`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=127531 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_slovak_ci

~ 2M records
CREATE TABLE `products_words` (
  `product` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `word` int(11) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `pw` (`product`,`word`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `word` (`word`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_slovak_ci
```

Now, if somebody is looking for keyword **"car"** it will take a look at table words like this:

`SELECT id FROM words WHERE word LIKE "car%" or reverse like "rac%"`
That's very fast.

The problem is, when I'd like to get unique products with this word. Those tables are joined with **words.id** and **products_words.word**.

I've used this sql:

```
SELECT products_words.product
FROM products_words
INNER JOIN words
    ON products_words.word=words.id
WHERE words.word like "car%" or words.reverse like "rac%"
GROUP BY products_words.product
```

[image]

I can't understand why it is looking at 1799211 rows? I need to tell to MySql to look first at **words** table, choose f.e. 10 ids and bring me **unique** products with these ids of word.

What I'am doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: In the absence of any aggregating functions, a GROUP BY clause is never appropriate. And it seems you want a composite index on some combination of (product,word)

Comment: But this is a different problem from the one about choosing 10 ids. So you should be clearer about which one you actually want to solve.

Comment: Yes, I agree. GROUP BY is bad in this case but I've hope, somebody will tell how to do it better. Should I just take all (not unique) products and make it unique by php then? Index with combination of (word,product) - It need to be in this order, has not helped, but now it's in use.

Comment: Both are important because the one solution of problem can change solution of second problem. That's the reason why I've leave GROUP BY in Sql. In result I need to know, what product to show on keyword "car". Maybe I'm doing it wrong at all.

Comment: Maybe. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Why do you show how your table look like in this way? Mysql has a nice way, see `SHOW CREATE TABLE words;` which is clear to everyone. You might also add the output of something like `SELECT * FROM words LIMIT 3;`, to give a minimal impression of the data in your table.

Comment: Most problems can be adequately described in a data set comprising just a dozen rows. Obviously, it's your choice whether or not to proceed with that endeavour

Comment: All right guys. When I'm making online demo I have found where the problem is. Table products_words has column product with varchar(20) and there was the problem why it didn't use index. Both products_words.product and words.id columns wasn't the same. Thank you all for time and help. Now it's like a bolt.

Comment: This is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. PS Please do not iuse "EDIT"s; edit your post to be clear now & forget about what it used to say. Please in code questions give a [mre]. Please research SQL performance basics & research how to post a question about SQL performance & reflect your research in your post. [ask] [Help] [meta] [meta.dba.se] PS Shouldn't it be `like "%rac"`, not `like "rac%"`? PS When there are no duplicate rows: `x where c or d` = `(x where c) union (x where d)`.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: @brook_river - I think my Answer gives an example of  philipxy's `x where c or d =...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ON products_words.word=words.id` seems totally wrong -- `word` is a `VARCHAR` but `id` is `INT.  Is there any need to have` id`?  Why not simply have` PRIMARY KEY(word)`on`words`?

`OR` does not optimize well.  Switch to `UNION`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT pw.product
    FROM ( ( SELECT id FROM words WHERE word LIKE 'car%' )
           UNION ALL
           ( SELECT id FROM words WHERE word LIKE 'rac%' )
         ) AS w
    JOIN products_words AS pw
      ON pw.word = w.id  -- This needs fixing!!  perhaps `w.word`??
```

The select with 'car%' finds only a few rows, and uses an index quite efficiently. Ditto for 'rac%'. The rest of the query works with those few rows. The version with OR blindly reads the entire table -- taking a lot longer. `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` may help. See also "handler counts" at [this blog post of mine](https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#handler_counts).

Comment: When he fixes the question, I'll fix my answer.  My point about `OR` vs `UNION` addresses the performance question.

Comment: @RickJames, relationship between word and id has been done in my last comment. I think, PK on word doesn't make sanse as the word can be found in reverse as well, or does?

Comment: could you please help to use this sql with f.e. "car" and "black". It'll be needed to search all products that has both keywords **car ** and **black** not only one or "or" one.

Comment: @brook_river - Your Question still needs "Those tables are joined with words.id and products_words.word." to be fixed.

Comment: I have no idea why I can't tag you. Anyway, it's been fixed. words.id is int(11) and products_words.word int(11) too. Both are joined this way.

Comment: I need to search for "car%" and "black%" for example. But for performance it needs to be like "Here you are 10k products from products_words for **car** and next I'm going to search for **black** only if common in those 10k products found first." I am not sure if it is possible to do it this way. Maybe I don't need intersect because in this case I probably would need first get all products for car, all for black and if there will be more than 5 values it's problem.

Comment: @brook_river - I would greatly appreciate it if you used, say, `word_id` wherever it is the `INT` and not the `VARCHAR`.

Comment: @brook_river - "intersect" is one way that it might be performed.  But more likely is to find all the "car", then check each of those for being "black" (etc).  A `FULLTEXT` index (with all the keywords in a single column) would be much more efficient.  (However, I don't know if "reverse" can be be handled.  Perhaps having both "car" and "rac" in the string.)

Comment: Rick, all for car, then being black is possible to do in one SQL? Fulltext like "carblackgreenredorangetruck"? I haven't wanted to take much space in database. In my way, you have one word only once and then only relationship products. In your way it will be "blackcar" maybe 5M times. It's not very effective for space saving. And then, you can't search for "car%" only "%car%" which is much slower. Or didn't I understand it right? Your last thing: if you have word like "4car" maybe mistake or some other kind of declension in other languages, it'll be reversed "rac4" and I am looking for "rac%".

Comment: Rick, my another idea is to find all keywords any intersect it by array_intersect() in PHP, but I'd like to prevent reading and using much more data as I need. Is it possible to find all products which have all keywords in one SQL? Thank you.

Comment: @brook_river - The column would have "car black green red orange truck ..." (spaces or other punctuation needed to separate "words").  Space -- Hmmm, I need to think about that.

Comment: @brook_river - "rac4" would be matched by `MATCH(col) AGAINST("rac* car* black*")`

Comment: @brook_river - Please explain why you need to search for reversed words.  There may be a different trick to achieve the real goal.

Comment: Rick, ```AGAINST("rac* car* black*")``` will search as ```or``` and I need to find intersect, so I need the match all rows which have all keywords. For reversed words - what do you mean? What is the better idea?

Comment: Rick, ```AGAINST('+car* +black*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)``` works but if I want also reversed it should be like ```AGAINST('+car* +black* rac*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)``` I need to think about it.

Comment: So, what will be the best idea? Make ```text``` col for every product and keep there all keywords and search them as ```AGAINST('+car* +black*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)```? Will this be the best way how to find products as fast as possible and keep space of database as low as possible?

Comment: There is about 10M rows. Do you think, it's not good to apply also for reversed words? For example, you're searching for keyword ```bubble``` and imagine, there is brand ```prettybubble```. If you're searching for ```bubble%``` you will find nothing but if you're searching for ```elbbub%``` there is a match. Because of **elbbub%** ytterp

Comment: Are there really enough like "prettybubble" to justify doing the reversal?  Just all "perttybubble" to the list.

Comment: It sounds like you need a mixture of AND and OR.  That gets tricky.

Comment: Maybe you're right about reversed words. AND, OR? Can't imagine what you mean.

Comment: I think you want ("rac" or "car") and ("black" or "kcalb")?